# python self calling unit test function not raising an error

Tags: python, unit-testing, recursion, python-unittest

I have a background in C and Fortran programming, however I have been trying to learn Python and object orientation. To help with some of my projects I have been trying to define some additional unit tests.

I have used the AssertAlmostEqual unit test, but I found that for large numbers it doesn't work so well, as it works to 7 decimal places (I think). When testing large exponents this becomes a bit useless. So I tried to define an assertEqualSigFig test for significant figures in stead of decimal places. This test was inspired by a stack over flow post, however I cannot find the original post I'm afraid.

This test works for integers floats and booleans however I wanted to see if it would also work with complex numbers. By splitting the numbers into the real and imaginary components and then calling itself. When this happens, no assertion Error is raised and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
import math

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    MyTestClass
    Adds additional tests to the unit test module:
    defines:
    - AssertEqualSigFig
        description: 
        - Used in place of the assertAlmostEqualTest, this tests two values
          are the same to 7 significant figures (instead of decimal places)
        args:
        - any two integers, booleans, floats or complex number
        returns:
        - assertion error if not equal to defined significant figures
    """

    def AssertEqualSigFig(self, expected, actual, sig_fig = 7):

        if sig_fig < 1:
            msg = "sig fig must be more than 1"
            raise ValueError(msg)
        try:
            if isinstance(expected, bool):
                if expected != actual:
                    raise AssertionError
                else:
                    return

            elif isinstance(expected, (int,float)):
                pow_ex = int(math.floor(math.log(expected,10)))
                pow_ac = int(math.floor(math.log(actual,10)))

                tolerance = pow_ex - sig_fig + 1
                tolerance = (10** tolerance)/2.0

                if abs(expected - actual) > tolerance:
                    raise AssertionError
                else:
                    return

            elif isinstance(expected, complex):
                #this part doesnt raise an error when it should
                a_real = actual.real
                a_imag = actual.imag
                e_real = expected.real
                e_imag = expected.imag
                self.AssertEqualSigFig(self, a_imag, e_imag)
                self.AssertEqualSigFig(self, a_real, e_real)

        except AssertionError:
            msg = "{0} ! = {1} to {2} sig fig".format(expected, actual, sig_fig)
            raise AssertionError(msg)
```

This test fails when complex numbers are involved. Here are the unit tests of the unit test that it fails:

```
import unittest

from MyTestClass import MyTestClass

class TestMyTestClass(MyTestClass):

    def test_comlex_imag_NE(self):
        a = complex(10,123455)
        b = complex(10,123333)
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, self.AssertEqualSigFig, a, b)

    def test_complex_real_NE(self):
        a = complex(2222222,10)
        b = complex(1111111,10)
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, self.AssertEqualSigFig, a, b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I think it is because the self.AssertEqualSigFig call does not raise an error. I'm sure there is a silly thing I have missed, But I am still learning. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I was being an idiot, I have found the solution

I should have been using

```
MyTestClass.assertEqualSigFig
```

and not

```
self.assertEqualSigFig
```